# How to create a plugin independent of theme in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to create a plugin in wordpress that should be independent of theme. That means it can work on any theme. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think your question show a lack of effort in research...

Comment: How are other plugins dependent on Wordpress themes?

Answer (score 0):

As you say you need to create a plugin. Plugins are all independent from Themes.

Check out the official [WordPress Codex entry](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) for that.

Also if it is more simple just create a function in a separate file and include it via you functions.php with `get_template_part()`. [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) are the Codex informations for that function.

Comment: Please try not to answer questions that do not meet SOF standards to help keep SOF away from low quality stuff.

Answer (score 0):

All plugins are independent from any themes by default, so you don't need to worry about it.

If your concern is to avoid conflicts with all themes, there's no common rule to achieve that. It depends on what type of plugin you are creating and how are you creating it. You just have to think of all possible issues that may come later by any theme and make a way to avoid these.

Comment: Please try not to answer questions that do not meet SOF standards to help keep SOF away from low quality stuff.